# How to cascade parent entity when persisting child in bidirectional

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, managed-bean

I have this child class called **Producto** that looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Producto implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @NotNull(message = "Por favor ingrese un valor")
    private String nombre;

    @NotNull(message = "Por favor ingrese un valor")
    @Column(length = 140)
    private String descripcion;

    @NotNull(message = "Por favor ingrese un valor")
    private double precio;

    @NotNull(message = "Por favor ingrese un valor")
    private String imagen1;
    @NotNull(message = "Por favor ingrese un valor")
    private String imagen2;
    @NotNull(message = "Por favor ingrese un valor")
    private String imagen3;

    private int megusta;
    private int nomegusta;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "comentario_producto", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<Comentario> comentario = new ArrayList<Comentario>();//


    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Subcategoria subcategoria = new Subcategoria();


    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Categoria categoria = new Categoria();


    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Sucursal sucursal;


    // Getters and setters
```

The parent class **Subcategoria** looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Subcategoria implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @NotNull(message = "Por favor ingrese un valor")
    @Column(length = 100)
    private String nombre;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = false, mappedBy = "subcategoria")
    private List<Producto> producto = new ArrayList<Producto>();

    // getters and setters
```

My child entity **Producto** has another Parent **Categoria** entity that looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Categoria implements Serializable {
    @NotNull
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @NotNull(message = "Por favor ingrese un valor")
    @Column(length = 100)
    private String nombre;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "subcategoria_categoria", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<Subcategoria> subcategoria = new ArrayList<Subcategoria>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = false, mappedBy = "categoria")
    private List<Producto> producto;
```

The entity Producto has another Parent called **Sucursal** that looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Sucursal implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String subgerente;

    @NotNull(message = "Por favor ingrese un valor en direccion")
    @Column(length = 120)
    private String direccion;

    @NotNull(message = "Por favor ingrese un valor en telefono")
    @Column(length = 36, unique = true)
    private String telefono;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "sucursal")
    private List<Producto> producto;
//Getters and setters
```

This is what my save method looks like on my managed bean that persists the childs **Producto** to parent **Sucursal**:

```
public void guardar() {

    List<Producto> prods = new ArrayList<Producto>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listproductos.size(); i++) {

        Producto p = new Producto();

        p.setId(listproductos.get(i).getId());
        p.setNombre(listproductos.get(i).getNombre());

        p.setDescripcion(listproductos.get(i).getDescripcion());
        p.setImagen1(listproductos.get(i).getImagen1());
        p.setImagen2(listproductos.get(i).getImagen2());
        p.setImagen3(listproductos.get(i).getImagen3());
        p.setPrecio(listproductos.get(i).getPrecio());
        p.setSucursal(newSucursal);

        p.setCategoria(categoriaDAO.read(listproductos.get(i).getCategoria().getId()));
        p.setSubcategoria(subcategoriaDAO.read(listproductos.get(i).getSubcategoria().getId()));

        prods.add(p);
        productoDAO.save(p);

    }

    newSucursal.setProductos(prods);

    sucursalDAO.save(newSucursal);

}
```

The logic on my managed bean is that I use a **@PostConstruct** annotation to load a entity **Sucursal** on my **jsf** page where I have a list of **Producto** that belongs to the parent entity **Sucursal**. I have a save method that persits the entity **Sucursal** with its corresponding child entities **Producto** and I also update the FK for the other parents entities of **Producto** (**Categoria** and **Subcategoria**). The problem is that whenever I persist the entity **Producto** it gets updated with the last fk from the list from **Producto** that I mentioned above. So my question is how can I update the parent fk of **Subcategoria** and **Categoria** on my child entity **Producto** for each child entity **Producto** that belongs to parent **Sucursal**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the `Sucursal` the parent entity.
Add the associations `Subcategoria` and `Categoria` on the `Producto` entity and then add the `Producto` entity to the `Sucursal` entity.

On saving the new `Sucursal` entity the cascade will handle the rest in persisting the `Producto` entity and adding the associations.

```
    Sucursal newSucursal = new Sucursal();
    newSucursal.setSubgerente("ABC");

    int size = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        Producto p = new Producto();
        p.setDescripcion("Description " + i);

        //add associations
        Categoria categoria = em.find(Categoria.class, 1);
        p.setCategoria(categoria);
        Subcategoria subCategoria = em.find(Subcategoria.class, 1);
        p.setSubcategoria(subCategoria);

        //add to new sucursal
        newSucursal.addProduct(p);
    }

    sucursalDAO.save(newSucursal);
```

On the `Sucursal` entity

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "sucursal")
private List<Producto> producto = new ArrayList<>();

public void addProduct(Producto p) {
    p.setSucursal(this);
    this.producto.add(p);
}
```

The code above execute the following SQL statements

```
insert into Sucursal (id, subgerente) values (1, 'ABC')
insert into Producto (id, categoria_id, descripcion, subcategoria_id, sucursal_id) values (1, 1, 'Description 1', 1, 1)
insert into Producto (id, categoria_id, descripcion, subcategoria_id, sucursal_id) values (2, 1, 'Description 2', 1, 1)
```